# Parse JSON in flutter, show data in label

Tags: flutter, dart

i have this json:

```
    [
    {
        "id": 988846211,
        "serviceTag": "1LJVKS2",
        "orderBuid": 1212,
        "shipDate": "2019-04-11T00:00:00Z",
        "productCode": ";E403",
        "localChannel": "ENTP",
        "productId": "dell-u2719d-monitor",
        "productLineDescription": "DELL ULTRASHARP U2719D",
        "productFamily": "Unknown",
        "systemDescription": "Dell U2719D",
        "productLobDescription": "Displays",
        "countryCode": "SE",
        "duplicated": false,
        "invalid": false,
        "entitlements": [
            {
                "itemNumber": "709-15308",
                "startDate": "2019-04-11T00:00:00Z",
                "endDate": "2022-04-11T23:59:59.999Z",
                "entitlementType": "INITIAL",
                "serviceLevelCode": "ND",
                "serviceLevelDescription": "C, NBD ONSITE",
                "serviceLevelGroup": 5
            },
            {
                "itemNumber": "865-41964",
                "startDate": "2019-04-11T00:00:00Z",
                "endDate": "2023-04-11T23:59:59.999Z",
                "entitlementType": "INITIAL",
                "serviceLevelCode": "ND",
                "serviceLevelDescription": "C, NBD ONSITE",
                "serviceLevelGroup": 5
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

and my main :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:dell_warranty/dellTok.dart';
import 'package:dell_warranty/model_json.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MaterialApp(
      home: new DellW(),
    ));

class DellW extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  DellWState createState() => new DellWState();
}

class DellWState extends State<DellW> {
  TextEditingController serviceTagg = TextEditingController();
  final String getToken = "https://apigtwb2c.us.dell.com/auth/oauth/v2/token";
  final String apiUrl =
      "https://apigtwb2c.us.dell.com/PROD/sbil/eapi/v5/asset-entitlements";
  String tagg;
  DellTok dellTok;
  ModelJson modelJson;
  String disc = "";
  List<ModelJson> data = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this.checkDell();
  }

  checkDell() async {
    var responseToken = await http.post(Uri.encodeFull(getToken), body: {
      "grant_type": "client_credentials",
      "client_id": "SECRET",
      "client_secret": "SECRET"
    });

    if (responseToken.statusCode == 200) {
      var responseTok = json.decode(responseToken.body);
      dellTok = DellTok.fromJson(responseTok);
      print(responseTok);

      setState(() {});
    } else {
      print(responseToken.statusCode);
    }
  }

  checkDellTagg(String serviceTag) async {
    var queryParameters = {
      'access_token': dellTok.accessToken,
      'servicetags': serviceTag,
    };
    var uri = Uri.https('apigtwb2c.us.dell.com',
        '/PROD/sbil/eapi/v5/asset-entitlements', queryParameters);

    var responseDell = await http.get(uri, headers: {});

    if (responseDell.statusCode == 200) {
      List<dynamic> responseD = jsonDecode(responseDell.body);
      List<ModelJson> modelJsonRes =
          responseD.map((responseD) => ModelJson.fromJson(responseD)).toList();

      setState(() {
        disc = modelJson.productLineDescription;
      });

    } else {
      print(responseDell.statusCode);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("Dell Warranty"),
        ),
        body: dellTok == null
            ? Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              )
            : Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    RaisedButton(
                        onPressed: () => checkDellTagg(serviceTagg.text),
                        child: Text(
                          "Flat Button",
                        )),
                    TextField(
                      decoration:
                          InputDecoration(hintText: "write servicetag..."),
                      controller: serviceTagg,
                    ),
                    Text(disc),
                  ],
                )));
  }
}
```

and my model_json.dart file :

```
class ModelJson {
  int id;
  String serviceTag;
  int orderBuid;
  String shipDate;
  String productCode;
  String localChannel;
  String productId;
  String productLineDescription;
  String productFamily;
  String systemDescription;
  String productLobDescription;
  String countryCode;
  bool duplicated;
  bool invalid;
  List<Entitlements> entitlements;

  ModelJson(
      {this.id,
      this.serviceTag,
      this.orderBuid,
      this.shipDate,
      this.productCode,
      this.localChannel,
      this.productId,
      this.productLineDescription,
      this.productFamily,
      this.systemDescription,
      this.productLobDescription,
      this.countryCode,
      this.duplicated,
      this.invalid,
      this.entitlements});

  ModelJson.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    serviceTag = json['serviceTag'];
    orderBuid = json['orderBuid'];
    shipDate = json['shipDate'];
    productCode = json['productCode'];
    localChannel = json['localChannel'];
    productId = json['productId'];
    productLineDescription = json['productLineDescription'];
    productFamily = json['productFamily'];
    systemDescription = json['systemDescription'];
    productLobDescription = json['productLobDescription'];
    countryCode = json['countryCode'];
    duplicated = json['duplicated'];
    invalid = json['invalid'];
    if (json['entitlements'] != null) {
      entitlements = new List<Entitlements>();
      json['entitlements'].forEach((v) {
        entitlements.add(new Entitlements.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['serviceTag'] = this.serviceTag;
    data['orderBuid'] = this.orderBuid;
    data['shipDate'] = this.shipDate;
    data['productCode'] = this.productCode;
    data['localChannel'] = this.localChannel;
    data['productId'] = this.productId;
    data['productLineDescription'] = this.productLineDescription;
    data['productFamily'] = this.productFamily;
    data['systemDescription'] = this.systemDescription;
    data['productLobDescription'] = this.productLobDescription;
    data['countryCode'] = this.countryCode;
    data['duplicated'] = this.duplicated;
    data['invalid'] = this.invalid;
    if (this.entitlements != null) {
      data['entitlements'] = this.entitlements.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Entitlements {
  String itemNumber;
  String startDate;
  String endDate;
  String entitlementType;
  String serviceLevelCode;
  String serviceLevelDescription;
  int serviceLevelGroup;

  Entitlements(
      {this.itemNumber,
      this.startDate,
      this.endDate,
      this.entitlementType,
      this.serviceLevelCode,
      this.serviceLevelDescription,
      this.serviceLevelGroup});

  Entitlements.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    itemNumber = json['itemNumber'];
    startDate = json['startDate'];
    endDate = json['endDate'];
    entitlementType = json['entitlementType'];
    serviceLevelCode = json['serviceLevelCode'];
    serviceLevelDescription = json['serviceLevelDescription'];
    serviceLevelGroup = json['serviceLevelGroup'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['itemNumber'] = this.itemNumber;
    data['startDate'] = this.startDate;
    data['endDate'] = this.endDate;
    data['entitlementType'] = this.entitlementType;
    data['serviceLevelCode'] = this.serviceLevelCode;
    data['serviceLevelDescription'] = this.serviceLevelDescription;
    data['serviceLevelGroup'] = this.serviceLevelGroup;
    return data;
  }
}
```

I'm trying to show the data in text field .

everthing ok when i post to get an access token and its saved and i used it to make a get req to the other url so i can get the data.
example :
i want to show

> productLineDescription

in text widget.
but im not going any farther than that!

how i am supposed to get data from model_json.dart and show it inside text widget?

sorry i am flutter newbie, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the `productLineDescription`, you have to call it like this:

```
productLineDescription = jsonDecode(myJson)[0]['productLineDescription'];
```

NOTE: `myJson` is your json source file.

You need the `[0]` because your json is inside a List.

Comment: Thanks Hisam!! , that did the thing, but i just get just !! the value of '0' 'productLineDescription'. i want to get all 'productLineDescription' not just the first !
i want [0]['productLineDescription'] and [1]['productLineDescription'] .....